# Ubuntu vivid box not running with vagrant

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using ubuntu vivid with Vagrant

https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/vivid64

when i do vagrant up

i get this

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

service hostname start

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
Failed to start hostname.service: Unit hostname.service is masked.
```

Is there any way to use vivid64 . i even tried

https://atlas.hashicorp.com/larryli/vivid64

but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as though Vagrant is throwing out an error relating to the hostname... try adding this to your vagrant file:

```
#host.vm.hostname = "[HOSTNAMEVM]"
host.vm.provision :shell, inline: "hostnamectl set-hostname [HOSTNAMEVM]"
```

Of course, set [HOSTNAMEVM] to your hostname.

What we are doing here is manually asking Vagrant to provision with a specific hostname, to attempt to fix the issue with the hostname service failing to start.

If this doesn't work, a pastebin with your Vagrantfile might help us see what might be the actual cause here.

Answer (score 1):

At first, try disabling the line with "hostname" on **Vagrantfile.**

change the line like

```
config.vm.hostname = "abcd"
```

to

```
# config.vm.hostname = "abcd"
```